# How to bind a key-chord to the `C-c` prefix?

Tags: key-bindings, key-chord-mode

I am using the package [key-chord](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/key-chord/tree/7f7fd7c5bd2b996fa054779357e1566f7989e07d). This package allows me to hit `x x` quickly instead of hitting `M-x`:

```
(key-chord-define-global "xx" 'execute-extended-command)
```

And here is another way to to set a key-chord (code below is equivalent to the above):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<key-chord> x x") 'counsel-M-x)
```

How can I set a key-chord for the `C-c` prefix?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473660/how-do-i-use-a-key-chord-combination-as-a-prefix-binding) question and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/89yofa/keychord_mode/) post are not the same as mine as he is creating his own prefix, whereas a I just want to bind `<key-chord> c c` to `C-c`

Answer (score 5):

I believe I found the solution:

```
(key-chord-define-global "cc" 'null)
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<key-chord> cc")  (kbd "C-c"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified solution from @WickedJargon when two different characters are used as key-chords:

```
(key-chord-define-global "qd" 'null)
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<key-chord> qd")  (kbd "C-c"))
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<key-chord> dq")  (kbd "C-c"))
```

where `qd` and `dq` mapped to `C-c` respectively.